# Is there any GUI tool for xdg-mime?

Tags: 19.04, gui, xdg

Usually, I should write a FileType.xml and use

```
xdg-mime install FileType.xml
```

then use

```
xdg-mime default xxx.desktop file-type
```

to set default application and

```
xdg-icon-resource install xxx
```

to set default icon. Finally, delete the FileType.xml.
To be honest, I can never remember the format of FileType.xml and the arguments of 'xdg-icon-resource'. It is a torture for me when I want to install new file type.
So, is there any GUI tool for xdg-mime?

Answer (score -1):

Use [Handlr](https://github.com/chmln/handlr).  A lot easier to set all of these.

##### Open a file/URL

```
handlr open ~/.dotfiles/pacman/packages.txt
handlr open https://google.ca
```

##### Set default handler for png files

```
handlr set .png feh.desktop
```

##### Set wildcard handler for all text files

```
handlr set 'text/*' nvim.desktop
```

##### Set default handler based on mime

```
handlr set application/pdf evince.desktop
```

##### List default apps

```
handlr list
```

##### Get the handler for a mime/extension

```
handlr get .png
feh.desktop
```

##### Launch a handler with given path/URL

```
handlr launch x-scheme-handler/https -- https://google.ca
```

Comment: Your answer could be a lot more useful with a description of how to do it.

Comment: Hello. A complete answer would say where to find that tool. How to install it. How to start it. How to use it. A lot easier then what? Just expanding on what @SorenA said.

Comment: OK, and this transcendends the question to "*is there a GUI for handlr to configure defaults*"?

Comment: This is NOT a GUI tool, so what's the point?